# How to input multiple source data for deploy in Caffe?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network, pycaffe

I am trying to test my network on new data, below is the part where I define data in my deploy.prototxt file

```
input: "data"
input_dim: 80 
input_dim: 3
input_dim: 227
input_dim: 227
input: "modaldata"
input_dim: 80 
input_dim: 3
input_dim: 227
input_dim: 227
input: "clip_markers"
input_dim: 80 
input_dim: 1
input_dim: 1
input_dim: 1
```

data is the RGB file and modaldata is a modal image of the same file (such as depth).

Using a python script I transform both of the image data, there is no error during transforming "data" however I get an error while transforming the "modaldata" at this line:

```
modalcaffe_in[ix] = transformer_modal.preprocess('modaldata',inputs)
And the error I get is:
```

> ```
> ..../python/caffe/io.py", line 136, in preprocess
>   self.__check_input(in_)
> ￼ File "/.../python/caffe/io.py", line 115, in __check_input
>   in_, self.inputs))
> Exception: modaldata is not one of the net inputs: {'data': (80, 3, 227, 227)}
> ```

Comment: how do you define `transformer_modal`? what is `inputs` that you pass to the transformer?

Comment: I have just fixed this problem, it was my mistake. I had initialized the transformers using the same template, I thought I was just creating instances of it by each call and the 'data' input was generic, I had to create separate initializers and it is fixed. Thx.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it.  That will allow Stack Overflow to properly archive this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just fixed this problem, it was my mistake. I had initialized the transformers using the same template, I thought I was just creating instances of it by each call and the 'data' input was generic, I had to create separate initializers and it is fixed.

```
    def initialize_transformer_RGB(image_mean, is_modal):
      shape = (10*8, 3, 227, 227) # shape = (1*16, 3, 227, 227)
      transformerRGB = caffe.io.Transformer({'data': shape})
      channel_mean = np.zeros((3,227,227))
      for channel_index, mean_val in enumerate(image_mean):
        channel_mean[channel_index, ...] = mean_val
      transformerRGB.set_mean('data', channel_mean)
      transformerRGB.set_raw_scale('data', 255)
      transformerRGB.set_channel_swap('data', (2, 1, 0))
      transformerRGB.set_transpose('data', (2, 0, 1))
      transformerRGB.set_is_modal('data', is_modal)
      return transformerRGB

    def initialize_transformer_modal(image_mean, is_modal):
      shape = (10*8, 3, 227, 227) # shape = (1*16, 3, 227, 227)
      transformermodal= caffe.io.Transformer({'modaldata': shape})
      channel_mean = np.zeros((3,227,227))
      for channel_index, mean_val in enumerate(image_mean):
        channel_mean[channel_index, ...] = mean_val
      transformermodal.set_mean('modaldata', channel_mean)
      transformermodal.set_raw_scale('modaldata', 255)
      transformermodal.set_channel_swap('modaldata', (2, 1, 0))
      transformermodal.set_transpose('modaldata', (2, 0, 1))
      transformermodal.set_is_modal('modaldata', is_modal)
      return transformermodal


    ucf_mean_RGB = np.zeros((3,1,1))
    ucf_mean_modal = np.zeros((3,1,1))
    ucf_mean_modal[:,:,:] = 128
    ucf_mean_RGB[0,:,:] = 103.939
    ucf_mean_RGB[1,:,:] = 116.779
    ucf_mean_RGB[2,:,:] = 128.68

    transformer_RGB = initialize_transformer_RGB(ucf_mean_RGB, False)
    transformer_modal = initialize_transformer_modal(ucf_mean_modal,True)
```